# JQuery permission denied error in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, permission-denied

There are many question asked with this subject but no question is similar to this. Please do not mark as duplicate.

I am using JQuery-Steps for wizard.I am getting permission denied error for following JQuery selector code in IE7

```
<div id="wizards-p-1">
 <input>......
</div>

$("#wizards-p-"+currentIndex+" input[type='text'], #wizards-p-"+currentIndex+" input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
                var input = $(this).get(0);
                if(input.validators){
                    validators = validators.concat(input.validators);
                }
            });
```

It is working fine in all the browser including IE8.

JQuery version is 1.8.3.

Could anyone suggest what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a large number of reasons you can get a "permission denied". Your post does not provide enough information to narrow down the cause therefore I would recommend you to take a look at the JQUERY list of issue to see if any is the one you are experiencing:

http://bugs.jquery.com/search?q=PERMISSION+DENIED+ie7&noquickjump=1&ticket=on